# Freeware tool for PL/SQL development

Tags: oracle, plsql, debugging

I'm currently looking for a good (free) tool to do some PL/SQL development on Windows against an Oracle XE database. I'm looking to develop some stored procedures, functions and packages, and need decent debugging capabilities (breakpoints, variable inspection etc.).

For the SQL side of database stuff, I've been using the TOADfree tool, which seems to have some limitations on the debugging side. Which other options are there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/sql_developer/index.html)

Quote from SQL Developer Site:

> Oracle SQL Developer is a free graphical tool for database development. With SQL Developer, you can browse database objects, run SQL statements and SQL scripts, and edit and debug PL/SQL statements.

Comment: And the new early adopter release 2.1 of SQL Developer does PL/SQL Unit Testing.

Answer (score 2):

I find Oracle SQL Developer very frustrating to use. It is slow and non-intuitive.
If you don't need PL/SQL Debugging, try [SQLTools](http://www.sqltools.net/) or [SQLTools++](http://www.sqltools-plusplus.org:7676/). The latter is a branch of the former with some 10g-specific features.
You may also want to check out [jOra Eclipse plugin](http://jora.luenasoft.de/index_en.html).

Comment: sqltools does not work on windows 10

Answer (score 0):

I always really liked using the [PL/SQL Developer](http://www.allroundautomations.com/) for my stored proc / funcs / trigger work - not free, but not expensive either, and totally worth it!

For interacting with Oracle, I used various of the Benthic Software's [Golden Tools](http://www.benthicsoftware.com/index.htm) which again aren't free, but not expensive at all and worth every penny; they make life with Oracle just that much easier!

Marc

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with Sergey Stadnik, I also find using Oracle SQL Developer is very frustrating and feel like it is slow and non-intuitive also.

On other hand I used Quest Toad and feel like mess due to heavy GUI bundled with view panes, toolbars and buttons also the font used within in PL/SQL editor is not much user friendly and horrible.

If your are using Windows I am telling you two tools, one *without PL/SQL* and the [king](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xb9K8IAdZNg) of its kind.

[**Intellij DataGrip**](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/download/#section=windows) in ***payable version*** and to learn download trial one.

on other hand with *PL/SQL editor and executable* features and also available in ***express edition***.

[**dbForge Studio**](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/oracle/studio/download.html) for mostly big gun rdbms engines with limited but full fill most of your requirements.

I'm sure by trying these, someone will be a fan!

Comment: I know this is a very old reply, but I am updating this just because of the higher views and with updated tools.